# How to replace double for loop with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Let's say i have a list. I then have to go through every element in that list and compare it to every other element in that list. Based on this comparison, i then need to add this element to another list. Currently, i solve this with for loops. But i want to optimize this by using vectorization from numpy.

My current solution is as follows:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = []
for x in a:
  for y in a:
    if comparison_function(x, y):
      b.append((x, y))
```

Where `comparison_function` just compares these two elements based on some criteria.
Obviously, this is not a great solution and i would like to solve this by vectorization. How would one achieve this?

Comment: *need to add this element to another list.* - you're appending a tuple `(x,y)`, is that intended to be as result of comparison or the elements `x,y`  as they are? And what's essentially a `comparison_function` ?

Comment: Does the order matter in the compare function? If not you could cut your runtime in half.

Comment: There is no general approach. It's `comparison_function` that you need to vectorize.

Comment: This question is meaningless without a specific `comparison_function`

Comment: You can simply use comprehension: `b = [(x,y) for x in a for y in a if comparison_function(x, y)]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a toy example that uses "less than" as the comparison function:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

You can use broadcasting to compute your comparison across all pairs:

```
m = a[:, None] < a[None, :]

# array([[False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#        [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
#        [False, False, False,  True,  True],
#        [False, False, False, False,  True],
#        [False, False, False, False, False]])
```

Finally, you can use [`np.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) to generate the indices of the `True` values that you can use to obtain the original values in `a`:

```
out = a[ np.argwhere(m) ]
```

out:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 5]])
```

You can optionally transform this back to a `list[tuple[int, int]]`, but you could also leave it as a `(N, 2)` shaped array.